# executable Jar file will not run: error in command prompt

Tags: java, executable-jar

Just having an issue with an exported executable Jar file. The whole project is working fine in eclipse but when export and run from command prompt am getting the following error
[image]

I think it is not able to find one of the images, but don't understand why it is throwing the error in jar file and not the project when run in eclipse. The project has a runner class that opens the main page which contains the smallframe class. These are all in the GUI package and any images used are in the src/Resources folder.

Any suggestions of where to look most welcome.

Edit: Just change code for all the images, but was getting an error for some "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object" so used the Class name "GenerateImages.class" instead of getClass(). this works in Eclipse but doesn't seem to work in the executable Jar file. [image]

Have put the code for createQuestionOne below, just wondering have I done something wrong:

```
public static void createQuestionOne(int startShape, int endShape, String symbols, int scenarioNum, String fileSaveLocation) throws IOException  
{

//shapes
final BufferedImage shapeLeft = ImageIO.read(GenerateImages.class.getClassLoader().getResource(startShape + ".png"));
final BufferedImage shapeRight = ImageIO.read(GenerateImages.class.getClassLoader().getResource(endShape + ".png"));
final BufferedImage questionMark = ImageIO.read(GenerateImages.class.getClassLoader().getResource("questionMark.png"));

//arrows
final BufferedImage rightArrow = ImageIO.read(GenerateImages.class.getClassLoader().getResource("rightArrow.png"));

//Transformations
final BufferedImage transform1 = ImageIO.read(GenerateImages.class.getClassLoader().getResource(symbols.substring(0,1)+ ".png"));
//
final BufferedImage none = ImageIO.read(GenerateImages.class.getClassLoader().getResource("None.png"));

final int width = 60;
final int height = 90;
final int smallWidth = 34;

final BufferedImage questionLayout = new BufferedImage(5*width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        Graphics2D reDraw = questionLayout.createGraphics();

        //set background to white
        reDraw.setColor(Color.WHITE);  
        reDraw.fillRect(0, 0, questionLayout.getWidth(), questionLayout.getHeight()); 

        //Question Line
        reDraw.drawImage(shapeLeft,0,15, null);
        reDraw.drawImage(rightArrow,width,15, null);
        reDraw.drawImage(transform1,width*2,30, null);
        reDraw.drawImage(rightArrow,width*2+smallWidth,15, null);
        reDraw.drawImage(questionMark,width*3+smallWidth,15, null);


try{
ImageIO.write(questionLayout, "png", new File(fileSaveLocation + "\\S" + (scenarioNum + 1) +"Q1.png"));
 ;}catch (Exception e) {}

//output correct answer as image

drawSingleShapeImage(shapeRight,scenarioNum, 1, fileSaveLocation);
drawDistractionShapeImage(none,scenarioNum, 1, 4, fileSaveLocation);
```

}

Comment: try reading the image this way `className.class.getClassLoader().getResource("yourImage")` and recreate the jar

Comment: Thanks that worked- some replacing to do throughout code. Was the error because I have hard coded the location which then changed when the jar was exported. Just want to understand so dont make same mistake twice

Answer (score 1):

You should never hardcode resources location because in simple word the environment in which it was executing might change when it is exported as a jar or war file One possible way to resolve your problem is to use

`getResource of java.lang.ClassLoader`-
As the javadoc says- it finds the resource with the given name. A resource is some data (images, audio, text, etc) that can be accessed by class code in a way that is independent of the location of the code.
The name of a resource is a '/'-separated path name that identifies the resource.

This method will first search the parent class loader for the resource; if the parent is null the path of the class loader built-in to the virtual machine is searched. That failing, this method will invoke findResource(String) to find the resource.

Or even try to load resources with `getResourcesAsStream()`

So in your case read the file using getResource() and re-create the jar